# How can I force Keycloak to use an Authorization header when connecting to an identity provider's token endpoint?

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

I've configured Keycloak as an identity broker, connecting to a custom OIDC provider that I've created.  During the authorization_code flow, Keycloak calls the authorization endpoint to get the code.  It then calls the token endpoint of my custom OIDC provider to exchange the code for an auth token.

I observe that Keycloak passes the client_id and client_secret as parameters in the request body, instead of as a Basic Authorization header.  I do not want to change the security configuration on my token endpoint.  Is there a way to cause Keycloak to send token requests to IdPs using the Auth header?

Relevant Keycloak code appears to be in `AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider`'s `generateTokenRequest` method.  This hard-codes the client-id and client-secret to be passed as params in the request body.

According to the OIDC specification, `client_secret_basic` is the default.  I'd be surprised if this is not supported by Keycloak; I just can't seem to figure out how to configure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature is not implemented.

Feature request: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-5956